# Blurring fisheye effect on a vertical text menu

Tags: javascript, menu, blur

I'm searching for existing scripts that will animate a vertical text menu by blurring text and zooming it according to the mouse pointer.

I'm trying to accomplish these actions:

1. OS X-like movement on mouse hover that can 'zoom' the text in and out
2. In an un-focused state, the text would be blurred
3. When a user moved their pointer closer to the text, the text would sharpen.

[Here's a Flash example](http://www.flashden.net/item/vertical-fisheye-menu/19994) that demonstrates some of the effects, but I'd really prefer to use JavaScript and not use 'down', 'up' and 'select' buttons, naturally.

Comment: The text animation is pretty easy using jQuery, but the blur effect is going to be very difficult in current browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this in Javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source script that I think could work for you (Or at least after minor modifications)

http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/fisheye-menu

And a tutorial on using it:
http://simply-basic.com/tools/fisheye-menu-for-your-website/

Edit:

I realized that the script above probably wouldn't handle text very well. Unfortunately blurring text is not easily done in javascript. It might be possible using the canvas element, but I was unable to find anything in a quick Google search and this would likely not be compatible with older browsers.

Here is another script that has a fisheye effect on text items in a list: http://aleph-null.tv/article/20080522-1839-265.xml/Text-based-Fish-Eye-Effect. This is probably closer to what you're looking for, but it's definitely not as smooth and doesn't allow you to blur text like flash does.

Answer (score 0):

Not a strict answer to this old question, but today you can implement something like this easily with CSS3 (without any javascript):

```css
.fancy-bar {
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.fancy-bar .item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.fancy-bar .item .ball {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.fancy-bar .item-black .ball {
    background-color: black;
}

.fancy-bar .item-red .ball {
    background-color: red;
}

.fancy-bar .item-green .ball {
    background-color: green;
}

.fancy-bar .item-brown .ball {
    background-color: brown;
}

.fancy-bar .item-orange .ball {
    background-color: orange;
}

.fancy-bar .item:hover .ball {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.fancy-bar .item .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: #777 0px 0px 2px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fancy-bar .item:hover .title {
    font-size: 13px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.fancy-bar .item-black:hover .title {
    color: black;
}

.fancy-bar .item-red:hover .title {
    color: red;
}

.fancy-bar .item-green:hover .title {
    color: green;
}

.fancy-bar .item-brown:hover .title {
    color: brown;
}

.fancy-bar .item-orange:hover .title {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-bar">

<div class="item item-black">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="title">First</div>
</div>

<div class="item item-red">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="title">Second</div>
</div>

<div class="item item-green">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="title">Third</div>
</div>

<div class="item item-brown">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="title">Fourth</div>
</div>

<div class="item item-orange">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="title">Fifth</div>
</div>
  
</div>
```